# I am having a Coldfusion / Sharpoint / Excel issue (Save)

Tags: excel, sharepoint, coldfusion

Ok, I need some high level help or some experienced help.

This is an environment issue, not specifically a code issue. There are no errors, and a file is saved.

I am using Sharepoint 2013's REST api, and am 'getting' an Excel file and saving from coldfusion cffile, action = 'write'. The resulting file is corrupt, in two ways.

1st, the .xlsm file extension changed to zip does not allow the new office structure/file to work.
2nd Excel file does not open in Excel, and Excel could not fix the corruption.

Soooo.. cffile action readBinary exists and a dump will show a 'yellow' box in the dump and truncates the data.

cffile action 'write' exists, 'writebinary' does not exist ...

When I pull the data from Sharepoint and dump it, its a standard blue box, looks like data, but is not truncated, nor is it 'yellow', like the 'readBinary' data.

Documentation says write does not need binary, it just recognized at binary.

// modifing the returned data with these functions does not help
    toBinary() fails
    toBinary(toBase64()) works but is corrupt
    toBase64() works  but is corrupt
    direct save works but is corrupt ...

getting from sharepoint as REST with binary flag does not  change the corrupt result

I tried to save in the underlying java, corrupt ...

Opening the corrupt file in notepad++ looks like an excel file also opened with notepad++ at the top of the file. (No obvious data issues)

Its strange but at the end of the file there appear to be file references to non-existent files, such as 0000.dat, trash.dat etc etc.

```
As the save, 
and the get (from sharepoint) are all 'working' 
and there would be too much code
so I am not posting specific code.
```

If you have any ideas that were not tried or have solved this specific problem I would love to hear your expert idea.

Thanks
Gary

Comment: The long and short of this is what coldfusion saves as .xlsm looks like .xlsm in notepad++ but it is not a proper zip file. If you change the extension to .zip, zip utilities can not open it. It would work on a non corrupt .xlsm file.....

Comment: Coldfusion dump : Structure = Blue, Binary = yellow; xml= white ... I can add this the toBase64 is definitely not correct. Its twice as long as the original file and a plain save. I did try winrar to 'fix corrupt zip files'. to no avail. The data was clearly not a good excel file and the message was early termination / premature termination.

Comment: @Leigh, I want to thank you for your comments, but I am looking for someone very specific and I suspect they might not exist. To answer this may require someone who has recent experience with Sharepoint 2013 Rest API and Coldfusion. I am grateful for your reply but there would be hundreds of lines of code that would not add to the understanding of the problem. At this point Guesses are excellent as I am punting to PowerShell and CSOM.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am going to eat my words, posting code might have been helpful. I still had 15 versions of the function, it really would have been confusing.

My original code has the binary part for Sharepoint but NOT the CFHTTP part. The answer/problem was there, coldfusion was not keeping the binary data. Once the parameter was added the 'dump' reflected the change with the 'yellow' binary color.

ex:For the cfhttp call!::

```
getAsBinary="true" // default is NO not AUTO -> should be auto adobe
```

Before:

```
rc.spActionURL = "https://{site}.sharepoint.com/sites/#this.sp365.orisApp#/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/#this.sp365.orisApp#/#arguments.libraryPath#/#arguments.folderName#/#arguments.fileName#')/$value";
//Perform SharePoint ODATA Query as long as access_token was successfully received.
cfhttp(method="get", charset="utf-8",
 url="#rc.spActionURL#", result="rc.spURLRequestResult", ) {
    cfhttpparam(name="Accept",  type="header", value="application/xml");
    cfhttpparam(name="Content-Type", type="header", value="application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12");
    cfhttpparam(name="Authorization",           type="header", value="#arguments.AccessToken#");
    cfhttpparam(name="binaryStringRequestBody", type="header", value="true");
} ;
```

AFTER:

```
rc.spActionURL = "https://{site}.sharepoint.com/sites/#this.sp365.orisApp#/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/#this.sp365.orisApp#/#arguments.libraryPath#/#arguments.folderName#/#arguments.fileName#')/$value";
//Perform SharePoint ODATA Query as long as access_token was successfully received.
cfhttp(method="get",
    getAsBinary="true" // default is NO not AUTO -> should be auto adobe 
    charset="utf-8",
   url="#rc.spActionURL#",
  , result="rc.spURLRequestResult", ) {
    cfhttpparam(name="Accept",  type="header", value="application/xml");
    cfhttpparam(name="Content-Type", type="header", value="application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12");
    cfhttpparam(name="Authorization",           type="header", value="#arguments.AccessToken#");
    cfhttpparam(name="binaryStringRequestBody", type="header", value="true");
} ;
```

Comment: Ah, don't you love it when something so small wreaks such havoc? Glad you finally figured it out (and kudos on your very diplomatic responses ;-)

Comment: Thanks and hey I appreciate the input. It looks like your earlier comments disappeared. I was trying to be careful in my communication, I was not unhappy with the suggestion to supply code... I just couldn't post everything I had tried!  Its easy to misunderstand on the web .. email etc.  Perhaps this will help someone, so I post my problem/fix.! :)

Comment: *Its easy to misunderstand on the web* Boy howdy, which is why responses like yours are very refreshing :) While creating a small repro case is the ideal, when you are in the throes of a problem sometimes it is challenging getting to that point. Incredible how easy it is *after* you solve the problem ;-) *RE: your earlier comments disappeared* Yes, I left a comment but guess you did not see it. Essentially while I suspected it might turn out to be a CF issue, if it was more Sharepoint specific, then my comments were just "noise", so I deleted them so as not to be a distraction ;-)